# "Invalid method name: 'execute'" error with Hive Client in Java

Tags: java, jdbc, hive

I am using CDH 4.2.1-1.cdh4.2.1.p0.5 in a cluster set-up with Cloudera Manager and I am trying to get the Hive example working using the Hive API in Java.
The hive version I am using is 0.10 (hive-hwi-0.10.0-cdh4.2.1.jar) and I am trying to setup a simple example following the instructions in this url: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveClient

When running my code (the source code at the end of the post), I am getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException: Invalid method name: 'execute'
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.executeQuery(HiveStatement.java:191)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.execute(HiveStatement.java:127)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.configureConnection(HiveConnection.java:126)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<init>(HiveConnection.java:121)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:104)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:579)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:221)
```

I've been searching in Google for a while now and I cannot find any solution to this problem.
Anyone can give me a hint what could be causing the issue?

Thanks in advance,

Robbbie

**Code causing the error:**

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class HiveJob {

private static Logger mLogger = Logger.getLogger(HiveJob.class);
private static String driverName = "org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";

public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    HiveJob myJob = new HiveJob();
    myJob.execute();
}

public void execute() throws SQLException {
    mLogger.info("Start HiveJob");
    try {
        Class.forName(driverName);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive://myHiveServer:9083/default", "", "");
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    String sql = "SHOW TABLES";
    System.out.println("Running: " + sql);
    ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    while (res.next()) {
        System.out.println(res.getString(1));
    }
    mLogger.info("HiveJob executed!");
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The jdbc url points to **myHiveServer:9083** , which is the metastore default port. You are getting that error because metastore does not support the same thrift api as hive server.
 You need to specify the host + port of hiveserver(1 or 2). The default port for it is 10000.

Answer (score 1):

Adding hive2 and changing port would not work alone. I have encountered with same issue and find that hive2 service needs to be start in cloudera VM. change the driver from above mentioned to "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver" and then port would 10000. it is working form me perfectly.The link you were using was old one and hive has been rewritten to support concurrent connections named as hive2.
this link will give you perfect code which would run properly for connectivity.
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveServer2+Clients

Answer (score 0):

Change 'jdbc:hive:' to 'jdbc:hive2:' and try again

Answer (score 0):

If you change to hive2 you also need to change the driver path to org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver

See:http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH4/4.2.0/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_topic_18_5.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to do 2 things for solving this issue,

1. Change the port number from 9083 to 10000. Bcz default port number is 10000 for hive thrift server...
2. And just you need to start hive thrift server... like this

   $ hive --service hiveserver &

If thrift server started then your output should be

```
   $ netstat -nl | grep 10000
     tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10000               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
```